# Leaflet on Chrome - Tiles are pending

Tags: google-chrome, leaflet, tiles

i have a website that uses leaflet apis for creating a map with custom tiles. It works fine if you zoom down and up slowly, but if you go fast the tiles stay pending. In chrome the website freeze and after nothing works, with firefox it says that the tiles are corrupted but the website continues to work fine. When I used google apis this never happened.
Anyone experienced the same issue? How did you solve?